# How Do I Upload a File using a Laravel Package?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, package, laravel-5.1

I have a file attachment feature in a Laravel package. I want the uploaded attachment to save **in the project directory using the package** and **NOT** within the package. Currently, the file is uploaded into the package `uploads` directory instead of the project `uploads` directory. Any suggestions on how to save this file in the right location?

Controller:

```
$attachment->spot_buy_item_id = $id;
$attachment->name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$attachment->created_ts = Carbon::now();

$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = '../../../resources/uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];          //3

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $attachment_hash = md5($tempFile);

    $new = $attachment_hash.'.'.$extension;

    // complete creating attachment object with newly created attachment_hash
    $attachment->hash = $new;
    $attachment->save();

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $new;  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

    chmod($targetFile, 0777);

}
else
{
    return "error";
}
```

Service Provider (I thought publishing the uploads folder might work - nope.)

```
public function boot()
{
    require __DIR__ . '/Http/routes.php';

    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/resources/views', 'ariel');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/resources/uploads' => public_path('vendor/uploads'),
    ], 'public');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/../database/migrations' => database_path('migrations')], 'migrations');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HERE WE GO. I used the (well-documented) the Storage facade to work with the local filesystem (project).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem

```
$attachment->spot_buy_item_id = $id;
$attachment->name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$attachment->created_ts = Carbon::now();

$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];          //3

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $attachment_hash = md5($tempFile);

    $new = $attachment_hash.'.'.$extension;

    // complete creating attachment object with newly created attachment_hash
    $attachment->hash = $new;
    $attachment->save();

    $tmpPath = $storeFolder . $ds;

    $targetFile =  $tmpPath . $new;  //5

    Storage::disk('local')->put($targetFile, file_get_contents($request->file('uploadedfile')));

}
else
{
    return "error";
}
```